# Getting facebook's indexed movies, music, schools etc

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, indexing

Is there anyway to get all of facebook's indexed content to use on my own site (through their API maybe)? Instead of having users type in their own favorite movies, they'd pick from a suggestion list basically.

Comment: It be will probably not allowed to have, but you can only query user/friend movie likes, and get their details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the [search API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching). It should let you pass partial names and filter by categories so you can generate a list for your autocomplete field.

Comment: Its not what OP has asked. OP needs a list of all movies/songs etc indexed on facebook :)

Comment: Right, but regarding "Instead of having users type in their own favorite movies, they'd pick from a suggestion list basically.", he could use the search API to generate that list.

Comment: It's a great idea actually but they don't provide a search by category. So if you do something like
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Orange&type=page
you'd get all sorts of stuff. I guess i could only show the results from the categories I am interested in, but they are not always going to be first on the list, so it would really slow it down.

Comment: You don't need to search by category, but you can filter the results you get by category (which is what I think you suggested in the second  part of your comment). It might slow it down a *tad*, but the slowness in this app is going to be from hitting the Graph API, not the operations you do on the data.

Comment: yeah thats what i meant. i'd have to keep calling the graph for more results if there are not enough matching my category, say in the first 5 results. But this is most likely what i'm going with. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way. Also, actually dont have a list. They create a page/link for any movie, place, song you update :)